# Views api: how to create a 'conditional' join

Tags: views

I have 3 tables:

```
Table 1      Table 2            Table 3
id_1 [...]   id_1, type, id_2   id_2 [...]
```

I want to join table 1 to table 3 by way of table 2. This is easy enough,eg.

```
$data['table3']['table']['join']['table1'] = array(
  'left_table' => 'table2',
  'left_field' => 'id_2',
  'field' => 'id_2',
);
$data['table2']['table']['join']['table1'] = array(
  'left_field' => 'id_1',
  'field' => 'id_1',
);
```

However, the intermediary table also has a 'type' attribute in it. What if I want to specify, *as part of the join*, what the type is? eg. I want something like this:

```
SELECT id_a.table1 FROM table3
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table3.id_2 = table2.id_2 AND table2.type = 'blah'
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.id_1 = table2.id_1;
```

To be clear, I want the condition to the part of the join, not after the fact (as a filter will remove null rows).

Answer (score 3):

I havent done this in Views 3, but try the following, adopted from Views2 blog post applied to your code:
http://www.agileapproach.com/blog-entry/views-2-table-aliases-and-extra-criteria

```
# I think you had typo in your join for table2 where
# you had as the final key 'table1'.
$data['table3']['table']['join']['table2'] = array(
  'left_table' => 'table2',
  'left_field' => 'id_2',
  'field' => 'id_2',
  'extra' => array(
      array('field' => 'type', 'value' => 'blah'),
    ),
);
```